# YouTube api doesn't return all subscriptions

Tags: json, api, youtube-api

Ok so I am using https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default/subscriptions?alt=json&start-index=1&max-results=50&v=2.1

To get subscriptions of logged in user. After first request I look at link elements to get all other subscriptions too. After all this processing is done I sometimes get strange results. 90% of times everything is OK.

In other 10% of times I get duplicated channels which leads to fact that some channels are missing.

Is there a way to solve this problem? Because it looks like this is an anomaly on YouTube side.

Comment: Are there any specific channels this is happening with?  Have you tried using v3 of the YouTube Data API?

Comment: It happens to random channels. I tested v3 and at first glance it looks OK. But I don't like the idea of having both v2 and v3 API calls in my script. And I don't want to fully use v3 only because it's still experimental and some things are not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please reach me with the broken examples.

I would also strongly suggest using Data API v3
"https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/list"
providing 'mine=true'

Comment: Yes it looks like it works in v3. But some other important things don't and there is also that low API call limit. 10 000 000 is just not enough for a number of users we have.

Comment: Let me now what other things don't work. Also the limit should be enough, if not you can always request more quota. If you are using it the right way, quota won't be your bottleneck.

Comment: Well in v3 every request must have dev key included. Now lets say an average user does like 40 requests per minute. Users are currently in average active for 45 minutes. That means that one user would use around 1800 tokens. Meaning in total with this limit I could have max 5555 users a day. And as far as I know not all requests are worth only 1 token. So then I get even less users per day. Is that right or am I interpreting this totally wrong?

Comment: One of things not working. https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=snippet&id=UC2NU0s1H0p9N4jvF7qV59vA&key=AIzaSyCR5In4DZaTP6IEZQ0r1JceuvluJRzQNLE

This should return "User account suspended" but it only returns empty list.